# node js local enviroment setup

Tags: javascript, node.js

i m trying to create local enviroment for learning node.js
i m following the link below
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_environment_setup.htm

i downloaded Windows Installer (.msi) on my computer and create a file named main.js

```
console.log("main.js");
```

and i double clicked node.exe

[image: node js directory]

on command prompt i m getting unexpected identifier exeption what s wrong?

[image]

---

After answers i also tried followings

- i created a new folder on my desktop and accessed to it. i got same error.
- i also used Windows Powershell

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't put your files into the `nodejs`-folder!
- Create a new folder (e.g. on your Desktop) and put `main.js` in it
- Start a command prompt (hit Windows+R and type `cmd.exe`)
- Navigate to your newly created folder using `cd`
- Run `main.js` by typing `node main.js`

---

If you enter `node` and press enter, you start something like a `console`. You can directly write JavaScript commands, e.g.

```
C:\Temp>node
> console.log('Hello World');
Hello World
undefined
>
```

If you started `node` and then enter `node main.js`, `node` will try to understand this command as JavaScript which is obviously not JavaScript. What you want to do is to enter `node main.js` directly:

```
C:\Temp>node main.js
Hello World
```

See the difference: In the first example you start `node` and then enter some JavaScript commands and in the second example you start `node` but with the parameter `main.js` which tells `node` not to start this "console" but to load this file and run it.

Comment: can you please check my edit above, i tried and i got same errors.

Comment: See my updated answer. I explained why it won't work like that. Also note that it's common to call the entry point to your application `index.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to type `node filename.js` from your command line shell.

You've run node (presumably by double clicking its icon) and are trying to type `node filename.js` from the node REPL instead of your shell.

Open Zsh, Bash, Windows Powershell or similar and run it from there.

Comment: can you please check my edit above, i tried and i got same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Access your file from a command Prompt like `node yourFile`. Also make sure you have installed node properly.To check that just type `node -v`, it should give you the current node version. If all these things are done then check for errors in `server.js`, which is `main.js` in your case.

Comment: can you please check my edit above, i tried and i got same errors.